# Definition of the kernel of a ring homomorphism with 1

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain, ring-homomorphism

I came across this problem: Let $R$ be a integral domain. Show that the map $b \mapsto ba$, with $a \neq 0$, is injective.

My proof went as follows:

Since $R$ is an integral domain, we have $ab = 0 \Leftrightarrow a = 0$ or $b = 0$. But $a$ is nonzero, therefore $b$ must be $0$ and thus the kernel of the map is $\{0\}$. Thus the map is injective.

First of all, is this correct?

Secondly, my friend pointed out that we're dealing with multiplication here, therefore I should use the multiplicative identity element $1$ for the definition of the kernel, and not the additive identity element $0$. I looking this up and turns out the kernel of a ring homomorphism is defined as follows:

$$ker(f) = \{a \in R : f(a) = 0\}$$

So my friend was wrong(?) But I'm curious, why is the definition like this? Usually, the kernel is just defined through the identity element. But in a ring with $1$ we have two identity elements to choose from.

Comment: Kernel of a ring map is always the elements that map to zero. Also, technically your proof relies on knowing the map is a ring homomorphism a priori (do your ring maps need to map $1$ to $1$?). You can do it more directly by saying that $ba=ca$ with $a\not=0$ implies $b=c$ (just by cancellation in an integral domain). Finally, the assumption about $R$ being finite is not necessary here.

Comment: I know about the definition of the kernel of a ring map. But my question was WHY is it like this? (Yes removed the part about R being finite. This would have been important for the second part of the problem which I didn't write about here)

Comment: On a high level, category theory says that this definition is the "correct" one. On a more tangible level, the kernel of a map $\phi$ should be defined so that it is an ideal and $R/\ker(\phi)\cong\text{im}(\phi)$ (first isomorphism theorem).

Comment: Some authors do not include 1 in the definition of rings, which are sometimes called 'rng'. Kernel's definition is the elements which goes to 0 i.e. additive identity which is always present in ring.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth But when we say "ring with $1$", there's no ambiguity.

Comment: I suggest the simplest proof based on the definition of injective: $ba=ca \implies b=c$. Indeed, we have $(b-c)a=0$. Now use that the ring is a domain.